# What would be the appropriate entrypoint for a docker image that is meant to act as a server?

Tags: docker, server, dockerfile

I'm pretty new to Docker. I'm currently trying to create a Docker image that contains a Samba server and have been struggling to figure out what the entrypoint should be. At first I was using "service smbd start" but I quickly found out that once the service is started the container would exit. Then I tried using "smbd -i" which launches the server in the foreground, but I found out that this will take control of the host terminal which is not what I want. I saw that the official httpd docker image will simply continue to running once started and returns control of the terminal to the user. How could I achieve this with my Dockerfile?

Comment: I believe this is what you looking for, Running docker in detached mode : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d

Comment: When you say "takes control of the host terminal", what do you mean?  The option that launches the server in the foreground, and makes the server process the only thing the container runs, is probably what you want.  (For practical purposes it's likely you want `CMD` and not `ENTRYPOINT`; it will make it easier to debug the container and enables a useful pattern or two.)

Comment: Use `smbd -i` and detached mode as Pavan commented above. `docker run -d `

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can be consider using supervisord for start the service. Supervisord takes the pid 1 as a process and run other processes what you want in background.